# How do I handle recursion and arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

So I have the following recursive function:

```
int printSeq(int last[], int n, int arr[], int longest){

     if(last[longest]==longest) return arr[longest];
     printf("%d ", printSeq(last, n, arr, last[longest]));
}
```

last is an array with locations pointing to array. Longest is the current location.

However when I run it I get strange values that are not in the array. Am I missing something?

The base case is when the last[longest] points to its own location

Comment: can you supply some arguments for a test case?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do here? This whole solution seems a bit flawed.

Comment: It is part of a larger solution. A work around for a linked list, because I hate using them.

Answer (score 10):

The function doesn't `return` any value after a `printf`.  This results in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Andre - Look over your code again. If `last[longest]` != `longest`, then no `return` statement is executed from that call. So what value is returned in that case? It could be total garbage.

Comment: @Andre - Well, perhaps not entirely your fault. A decent compiler should warn you that not all code paths `return` a value. You might want to try turning up your compiler's warning levels.

Comment: @Andre you only return a value if last[longest]==longest. If that's not the case, you let the function go haywire, by not returning anything.